Mint 22 Update Manager fails to find package it says should be updated
After upgrading to Mint 22 (by following https://linuxmint-user-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upgrade-to-mint-22.html ) and rebooting, Update Manager advises I should update org.kde.Platform but when I try, no update runs and there's no error message.
sudo apt install org.kde.Platform does not find it to update.
How may I force that update?

that doesn't seem to be an apt package thing, but a flatpak layer; try
flatpak update

instead

Solved by [i]flatpak -v update[/i] as suggested by xenopeek elsewhere. With that solved, other updates proceed OK.
